# Circularly shifting (or rotating) the digits the digits of a number in Python

Tags: python, digits

Suppose I have the following input:

```
1234
```

How can I get the following output?

```
3412
```

This is obtained by circularly shifting (or rotating) the digits of the input twice.

I have tried the following code:

```
number = 1234
bin(number >> 1)
```

but it is not producing the results I was expecting.

Comment: First of all you should probably save it as a string, not an integer

Comment: That's called a right rotation by the way.

Comment: "but i am getting 3412 as output". That's strange, on my machine that code prints 0b1001101001. I think the first thing you should do is look up the documentation for ">>" to confirm whether "right shifting" does what you think it does.

Comment: @Kevin i am trying to convert number into binary then right shift then binary into number

Comment: Numbers **do not have** digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `>>` operator does a [binary bitshift](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations).

It moves the binary representation of `1234` on place to the right, discarding the rightmost (least significant) bit.

Therefore you code does not result in `3412`.

You probably want string rotation instead:

```
>>> def rotr(string, n):
...     return string[n:] + string[:n]
... 
>>> rotr("1234", 2)
'3412'
```

You can also convert it back to an integer afterwards

```
>>> int('3412')
3412
```

Comment: thanks!! again like @onno the logic is simpler than what i thought to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

I would convert to string to be able to slice it.

```
number=1234
right_shift_no = 2
new_number = int(str(number)[right_shift_no:]+str(number)[:right_shift_no])
```

Comment: thanku!! Logic of solving this problemof mine is complicated. thanks for sharing a easy logic

Answer (score 3):

Here's the lazy man's version:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> number = 1234
>>> d = deque(str(number))
>>> d.rotate(2)
>>> result = int(''.join(d))
>>> result
3412
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must stick with numbers (though I'd go with the string option first)

```
from math import log10, floor
s = 2  # digits to shift by
p = 10 ** s  # that as a power of 10
n = 1234
rhs = n // p  # right hand side of result (here 12)
rhs_n = floor(log10(rhs)) + 1  # number of digits in rhs
rhs + (n % p) * 10 ** rhs_n  # add other digits, n % p, shifted by size of rhs
```

and all together in a function

```
from math import log10, floor

def rotate(n, s):
    p = 10 ** s
    rhs = n // p
    return rhs + (n % p) * 10 ** (floor(log10(rhs)) + 1)
```

Comment: hey thanks!!You need to explain me as its lil bit different from what i thought

Comment: @TanyaChaudhary explained